# Measure on torus invariant under multiplication

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory, arithmetic-dynamics

Let $T: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a multiplication by $ \beta >1$ mod $1$. Show that $h(x) d x$ is $T$-invariant where

$$h (x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \beta^{-n} \chi _{[0,T^n (1)]} (x)$$

($\chi$ is indicator function)

I can do this for $\beta =2$ when the indicator functions are trivially equal to one, and this is a constant times Lebesgue' measure. Don't know how to do the general case.

---

Edited: there was a mistake,$\chi _{[0,T^n ]}$ should be $\chi _{[0,T^n (1)]}$. I am told that this can be found in some paper of 'Perry' but could not find exact references.

Comment: $h$ is a function or a measure?

Comment: h(x) is a function that is the density of measure with respect to Lebesgue' measure, h(x) d(x) is my way of denoting this, measure. Sorry for nonstandard notation.

Comment: The notation is standard, but also the exercise. See my hint.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You must show that
$$
\int_0^1\varphi h=\int_0^1(\varphi\circ T)h
$$
for any integrable function $\varphi$ (with respect to your measure) or, equivalently, that this happens for all functions $\varphi=\chi_{[0,t]}$ for $t\in[0,1]$. For example, the left-hand side becomes $\int_0^1\chi_{[0,t]} h=\int_0^t h$.

PS: You need to clarify in your source what is meant by $\chi_{[0,T^n]}(x)$, although it could be $\chi_{[0,T^n(x)]}$.

Comment: Edited the question. Yes, I know that it would suffice, because it is equivalent to calculating if the equality holds for intervals (which generate borel sets). This looks doable on the first sight, but then I cant figure it out.

Comment: @wroobell I see. Then the reference is W. Parry, On the $\beta$-expansions of real numbers, Acta Math. Acad. Sci. Hungar. **11** (1960), 401-416.